# How to generate a Google Static map from GeoJSON?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is it possible to get an URL to generate a static Google Map from a GeoJSON file?

Thanks,
Jérémy

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Nope, nothing so far...

Comment: I have this working. I'll post my code in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is how I converted a custom [MapBox](http://mapbox.com) `.geojson` file to a `Static Google Map`:

**Map**

This is a `MapBox` map converted to `.geojson` that I am using: https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jeitnier.icm51ajc/markers.geojson. It's got a `Polygon` boundary  with a blue fill & stroke and a `LineString` line with a red stroke.

**Code**

```
$url      = 'https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jeitnier.icm51ajc/markers.geojson';
$response = \Utility::curl($url); // This is just a standard cURL function that returns the contents of the JSON
$geojson  = json_decode($response);
$paths    = '';
$markers  = '';

foreach ($geojson->features AS $feature)
{
    $properties = array();

    if ('LineString' == $feature->geometry->type OR 'Polygon' == $feature->geometry->type)
    {
        $properties['stroke']       = substr($feature->properties->stroke, 1, 7);
        $properties['stroke_width'] = $feature->properties->{'stroke-width'} - 1;
    }

    if ('LineString' == $feature->geometry->type)
    {
        $paths .= '&path=color:0x' . $properties['stroke'] . '99|weight:' . $properties['stroke_width'];

        foreach ($feature->geometry->coordinates AS $set)
        {
            // put them in reverse order (lat/long) and convert to string
            $paths .= '|' . $set[1] . ',' . $set[0];
        }
    }
    elseif ('Polygon' == $feature->geometry->type)
    {
        $properties['fill']         = substr($feature->properties->fill, 1, 7);
        $properties['fill_opacity'] = $feature->properties->{'fill-opacity'} * 100;

        $paths .= '&path=color:0x' . $properties['stroke'] . '|weight:' . $properties['stroke_width'] . '|fillcolor:0x' . $properties['fill'] . $properties['fill_opacity'];

        foreach ($feature->geometry->coordinates AS $coordinate)
        {
            // iterate over individual coordinate set
            foreach ($coordinate AS $set)
            {
                // put them in reverse order (lat/long) and convert to string
                $paths .= '|' . $set[1] . ',' . $set[0];
            }
        }
    }
    elseif ('Point' == $feature->geometry->type)
    {
        $markers .= '&markers=scale:' . $this->scale;
        $markers .= '|' . $feature->geometry->coordinates[1] . ',' . $feature->geometry->coordinates[0];
    }
}

// set map parameters
$params = array(
    'key'    => Config::get('custom.google_map_api_key'),
    'zoom'   => 16,
    'size'   => '300x300',
    'format' => 'png32',
    'scale'  => '2',
    'sensor' => 'false',
);

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?' . http_build_query($params) . $markers . $paths;
```

You will have to adjust things to fit your specific needs but this is the gist. The code I wrote only supports markers, polygons & lines as that was all I needed.